# Problema para fazer converter com chave composta em jsf, selectonemenu

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, primefaces-5.2

Estou fazendo um selectOneMenu onde o itemvalue será uma chave composta. A qual será separada por hífen. Contudo na hora de enviar, o método getasobject é chamado várias vezes, enviando todos os items do meu selectonemenu e não apenas o selecionado.

```
    @FacesConverter(value = "conversorProd")
public class ConversorProdutoDB implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent uiComponent, String value) {
        if (value != null && !value.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                String[] split = value.split("-"); //assumindo que será separado (idProduto - idGradeSelecionada)

                if (split.length > 1) {
                    GradeProduto gradeProd = PadraoDAO.carregar(GradeProduto.class, Long.valueOf(split[1]));
                    Produto prodComGrade = gradeProd.getProd();
                    prodComGrade.setGradeSelecionada(gradeProd);
                    return prodComGrade;
                } else {
                    return (Produto) PadraoDAO.carregar(Produto.class, Long.valueOf(split[0]));
                }
            } catch (ExceptionBancoDeDados ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ConversorProdutoDB.class.getName() + "-Erro ao executar conversor de produto").log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext facesContext, UIComponent uiComponent, Object value) {

            return value != null ? value.toString() : "";

    }
}


          <p:selectOneMenu value="#{transferenciaEstoqueMB.transferenciaDet.transProdOrigem.prod}"
                                     filter="true" filterMatchMode="contains"
                                     converter="conversorProd"
                                     id="slcProd"
                                     >
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione" noSelectionOption="true"/>
                        <f:selectItems value="#{transferenciaEstoqueMB.listProduto}"
                                       var='p'
                                       itemLabel="#{p.cod}-#{p.descricao}"
                                       itemValue="#{p.idComposta}"/>
                        <p:ajax listener="#{transferenciaEstoqueMB.onChangeProd()}"
                                process="@this"  update="@(.transProd)"/>
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: Já tentou implementar no converter getAsString para passar a chave composta ? Pois o retorno do Object é o valor que está passando esse método.

Comment: já é a chave composta. Observe o itemvalue. @MarioHayasakiJúnior
Fiz isso com o id do Produto simples para testar e funcionou. Só não funciona na chave composta. Aí para resolver isso aí, criei a chave composta no getAsString.Se ninguém souber o que pode ser, vou postar a resposta. Achei meio sem lógica isso...